# C# memory address and variable

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

in C#, is there a way to

1. Get the memory address stored in a
   reference type variable?
2. Get the memory address of a
   variable?

EDIT:

```
int i;
int* pi = &i;
```

- How do you print out the hex value of pi?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For #2, the `&` operator will work in the same fashion as in C.  If the variable is not on the stack, you may need to use a `fixed` statement to pin it down while you work so the garbage collector does not move it, though.

For #1, reference types are trickier: you'll need to use a `GCHandle`, and the reference type has to be blittable, i.e. have a defined memory layout and be bitwise copyable.

In order to access the address as a number, you can cast from pointer type to `IntPtr` (an integer type defined to be the same size as a pointer), and from there to `uint` or `ulong` (depending on the pointer size of the underlying machine).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class Blittable
{
    int x;
}

class Program
{
    public static unsafe void Main()
    {
        int i;
        object o = new Blittable();
        int* ptr = &i;
        IntPtr addr = (IntPtr)ptr;

        Console.WriteLine(addr.ToString("x"));

        GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(o, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        addr = h.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        Console.WriteLine(addr.ToString("x"));

        h.Free();
    }
}
```

Comment: #2, that is cool. but how can you get the memory address as a string. say int i; int* pi = &i; I cannot print it using Console.WriteLine(pi);
I expect something like 0x0439ecc4 to be printed. Any clue?

Comment: Console.WriteLine("0x" + pi.ToString("x") would print the hex value

Comment: @Hamish, pi.ToString("x") raise compilation error. "Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'int*'"

Comment: You need to use the "->" operator. pi->ToString()

Comment: @rism, the OP wants the value of the pointer reinterpreted as an integer, not the value pointed to by the pointer.  Casting `int*` to `IntPtr` allows it.

Answer (score 5):

Number 1 is not possible at all, you can't have a pointer to a managed object. However, you can use an IntPtr structure to get information about the address of the pointer in the reference:

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(str, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle);
string pointerDisplay = pointer.ToString();
handle.Free();
```

For number 2 you use the & operator:

```
int* p = &myIntVariable;
```

Pointers of course have to be done in a unsafe block, and you have to allow unsafe code in the project settings. If the variable is a local variable in a method, it's allocated on the stack so it's already fixed, but if the variable is a member of an object, you have to pin that object in memory using the `fixed` keyword so that it's not moved by the garbage collector.

Comment: Weired, why code can not compile with string str = "hello"; string* ptr = str; ? any idea?

Comment: My bad, that is actually not possible at all. You can't have a pointer to a managed object, you have to use an IntPtr.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't say what it is that you don't like, it's rather pointless...

Comment: `GCHandle.ToIntPtr` returns an internal representation of the handle itself, not the address of the object it points to.  If you create multiple handles for the same object, `GCHandle.ToIntPtr` will return different results for each handle.  It is `GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject` that returns the address of the object the handle points to.  Please see [GCHandle.ToIntPtr vs. GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2006/10/09/gchandle-tointptr-vs-gchandle-addrofpinnedobject/) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question most correctly:

#1 is possible but a bit tricky, and should be only done for debugging reasons:

```
object o = new object();
TypedReference tr = __makeref(o);
IntPtr ptr = **(IntPtr**)(&tr);
```

This works for any object and actually returns the internal pointer to the object in memory. Remember the address can change at any moment because of the GC, which likes to move objects across the memory.

#2 Pointers aren't objects and thus don't inherit *ToString* from them. You have to cast the pointer to *IntPtr* like so:

```
Console.WriteLine((IntPtr)pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            int a = 10; 
            int b = 20; 
            int* aPtr = &a;
            int* bPtr = &b;
    
            Console.WriteLine($"Address of a: {(int)aPtr}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Address of b: {(int)bPtr}");
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Detailed explanation can find here
Link: https://youtu.be/OPzUnlDBB_I?feature=shared