# How to know the memory adress of elements in list c#

Tags: c#, list

I have:

```
        List<double> w = new List<double>();
        w.Add(1);
        w.Add(2);
        w.Add(1);
        w.Add(4);
        w.Add(5);
        w.Add(1);
        foreach (double num in w)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(num);
        }
```

Which writes

```
1 2 1 4 5 1
```

How do I print the memory location of each number, I tried  &num, but get error.

Comment: Isn't that partly the point of c# - you're not supposed to bother with the actual memory addresses since memory management is largely handled for you? Is there a specific reason you need the addresses?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# memory address and variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588817/c-memory-address-and-variable)

Comment: well, I need to do some contiguos memory passing, and tell some other function where to start pointing

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @cMinor If this is for interops then you should marshal the array / items instead of using `unsafe`.

Comment: @cMinor: you don't do it that way in C#. If you need to pass a contiguous block of doubles to unmanaged code, allocate an array and pass it. p/invoke marshaler will pin the array in memory for the duration of the call, take its address and pass it.

Comment: could you please post any example of `p/invoke marshaler`

Comment: @cMinor - can you give some more information on what you're trying to achieve so we can give you a relevant example.

Comment: I want to pass the initial memory of the list to some function (if it were an array I would pass it `&array[0]`), so thats why I need the adress of the first element of the list...

Comment: cMinor - There is tons of information on this website.  How about comming back when you got a specfic question.  You should not go about what you want to do it, per your question, think of a new question and asked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using P/Invoke and you want to pass a list of elements to a C function, you can use attributes in most cases to have the work done for you. Eg.

```
[DllImport("x.dll")]
extern void PassDoubleArray([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]Double[] array);
```

If you have something a bit more complex and need to do it manually, the `Marshal` class has most of what you need to get it done.

First, allocate some unmanaged memory - enough to store your object or array, using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, which will give you an `IntPtr`. You can copy .NET primitives to and from the unmanaged memory by using `Marshal.Copy.` For non primitives, create structs and use `Marshal.StructureToPtr` to get an IntPtr for it. When you're done with the unmanaged memory, make a call to `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` to free it up.

eg, this will do the equivalent of the above attribute, but more long-winded.

```
[DllImport("x.dll")]
extern void PassDoubleArray(IntPtr array);

List<Double> vals = new List<Double>() { ... }
IntPtr unmanaged = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(vals.Length * sizeof(Double));
Marshal.Copy(vals.ToArray(), 0, unmanaged, vals.Length);
PassDoubleArray(unmanaged);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanaged);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is now way to get a memory location in c#. Memory addresses are tabu in the .NET Framework, because the garbage collector may rearrange the stuff on the heap.

All you can use in your case is the list index. You could reformulate your loop like:

```
for (i = 0; i < w.Count; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(w[i]);
}
```

If you would like to reference an item directly, then use a reference type like:

```
class MyDouble
{
    Public double Num { get; set; }
}
```

And then declare:

```
var w = new List<MyDouble>();
w.Add(new MyDouble{Num = 1});
var referenced = new MyDouble{Num = 2};
w.Add(referenced);
a.Add(...);
Console.WriteLine(referenced.Num);
referenced.Num = 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is yet another reason why not to use a memory location. If you add items to the list, the internal array used to store the list items might be resized, i.e. a new array having the double size of the previous one will be created and the items will be copied into the new array. The reference trick shown in my last post, however, would still work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `unsafe` code in order for this to work. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zcbcf4ta%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for more details.